# Angular 2 module.id

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

In tsconfig.json I have set the my compilerOptions as below in order to put all my .map and .js file into output folder.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./app/output"
  }
}
```

In system.config.js, I have configured the packages as below in order to load the main.js.

```
packages: {
      app: {
        main: './output/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
```

and here is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

and question is when I loaded the project, why the module.id will get the path like localhost:3000/app/output/app.html instead of localhost:3000/app/app.html. It has causing me an error to load the html. The module.id should get the root path relative to the index.html right ?

Image below shows my project's tree structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html file add

```
<base href="/">
```

according to the [Angular2 router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) documentation.